# RewriteRule: How to make the second argument optional

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to create a rewrite rule, were the second argument MUST be optional. But, for some reason, i don't know how to make so:

```
RewriteRule ^galeria/place/country/(.*)/([0-9]+)/?$ gallery/geography.php?country=$1&p=$2 [L]
```

Considering one case for testing purposes, let's pick the country Argentina, this is all the possibilities:

```
http://www.mywebpage/galeria/place/country/argentina
http://www.mywebpage/galeria/place/country/argentina/
http://www.mywebpage/galeria/place/country/argentina/3
http://www.mywebpage/galeria/place/country/argentina/3/
```

Remember that the last argument, the page, is optional

I know i'm close but i can't figure out how to make the second argument, on the rewrite rule, optional. Help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^galeria/place/country/([^/]+)(?:/(\d+))?/?$ gallery/geography.php?country=$1&p=$2 [L,QSA]
```